# Apply base shipping cost for all orders to show in header_minicart

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, mini-cart

I am looking for a way if possible to apply a base shipping cost to all orders that will display in the mini cart in the header then when the customer goes to checkout they can get a more accurate shipping estimate using the normal functions.

Firstly is this possible

Secondly if it is would any one know where I could start.

Used the answer below with this in /checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml around line 82;
`<?php 
         $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); //Total object
         $grandtotal = $totals["grand_total"]->getValue(); //Grandtotal value 
         echo $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($grandtotal , true, false);
        ?>`

my header now displays subtotal and an estimated grandtotal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to apply a default destination to a new quote, so that Magento thinks it will be shipped there and thus show shipping costs to that location. Luckily there's a small extension that does just that: http://www.rapidcommerce.eu/blog/2012/04/allways-show-shipping-costs-in-magento/ (note the updated version, it's still working on newer versions of Magento even though it was released in '12).

You can find the settings in the configuration under Shipping Settings.

Comment: Was a great start to my solution see edit above for full solution